# Outlook.com rejects: 550 SC-001 (BAY004-MC5F13)

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, spam

I am operating a cluster of 3 dedicated machines for a webapp, each of those uses sendmail as MTA. Hostnames are node1.domain.com node2.domain.com node3.domain.com

Unfortunatelly outlook.com rejects to deliver mails to its users from my servers telling me the following:

> X-Authentication-Warning: node1.domain.com: www set sender to
>   support@domain.com using -f

AND

> Action: failed Status: 5.0.0 Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 SC-001
>   (BAY004-MC5F13) Unfortunately, messages from 136.243.73.202 weren't
>   sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of
>   their network is on our block list.

This last message is strange as the ip does not apear to be on any blacklist I checked.

How could I fix the config regarding the authentication warning? I guess this is the main reason for the rejection. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hotmail has its own private blacklist. And that warning message probably has nothing to do with it. (And yes I'll probably keep calling it Hotmail until the end of the universe.)

Comment: I have already contacted their support as suggested in the returned message. Do you have any idea how to add more reputation to the sender? It looks like this provider ist not the only one blocking. My guess is that the sendmail config is not 100% right and adds to the spam score.

Comment: If you figure out how to deliver to Microsoft successfully, you can get rich. It's beyond me. They block everyone and aggressively. With all the lost mail it's kind of surprising that anyone even uses them for email service...